# What is a general solution of the differential equation $xy''-(2x+1)y'+(x+1)y=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is a general solution of the differential equation $$xy''-(2x+1)y'+(x+1)y=0$$ in any interval not containing the origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one thing to notice
$$xy''-(2x+1)y'+(x+1)y=0$$

we can split like this
$$
x(y'' - y') - (x + 1)(y' - y) = 0
$$
or
$$
x\frac{d}{dx}(y' - y) - (x + 1)(y' - y) = 0
$$
setting $v = y' - y$ we have
$$
x\frac{dv}{dx} - (x+1)v = 0
$$
so you can solve a couple of first order odes. That being said, are you meant to solve with series approach?

Comment: +1. Is it a separable-variable ODE?

Comment: This is more than sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: @the_candyman after the first one it will not, you will solve an equation of the form $y’ -y = g(x)$ if that ode is integrated nicely, I can’t be sure, as I have not looked that far. But the equation at hand looks like it could have been set to solve with a series approach but the OP has not said otherwise.

Comment: Clear, you are right. Maybe the solution involves nonstandard function like Lambert function.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method, notice the groups :

- $(-1y'+1y)$
- $x(1y''-2y'+1y)$

When you see Pascal's Triangle coefficients $1,1$ or $1,2,1$ or $1,3,3,1$ these appears for successive derivatives of $ye^x$.

In our case $ye^{-x}$ since there are negative signs, so let set $ye^{-x}=u$

Reporting in the ODE reduces to $$xu''-u'=0$$